# PHP assign class member a value and access in another method within the class

Tags: php, class

I am having trouble getting value of the class member setting in another method within the class. I have tried use `__get` and `__set` magic methods, `getter` and `setter` as well as two more approach as in the code but none of them working.

What I am looking is if the type is `U` than the javascript variable should be used else not.

### Approach one

```
class UserRatings extends User {

    private $postType; // string


    public function headJS(){

        // access postType value from getItem method
        // this outputs nothing (blank)
        if ($this->postType = 'U') {
            # code...
        }


    }


    public function getItem($post){

        $this->postType = $post['data']['post_type'];

        $markup = 'html markup to render the output';

        return $this->postType; 

    }

    public function isType($post)
    {
        if ($post == 'U') {
            $this->isType = true;
        }

        return $this->isType;
    }


}
```

### Approach two

```
class UserRatings extends User {

    private $isType = false;


    public function headJS(){

        // even this doesnt't work too
        if ($this->isType) {
            # code...
        }

    }


    public function getItem($post){

        $markup = 'html markup to render the output';

        $type = $post['data']['post_type'];

        $this->isType($type);

    }

    public function isType($post)
    {
        if ($post == 'U') {
            $this->isType = true;
        }

        return $this->isType;
    }


}
```

Comment: **`$this->`** please SCOPE :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't get what do you mean. Can you please explain?

Comment: if ($postType = 'U')  replace to  if ($this->postType = 'U')

Comment: Just realized that your function has the same name as your property. Not sure how php interprets that

Comment: Oh I am sorry, It is using `$this->` in my code but while formatting to post I missed it. Sorry let me update.

Comment: @113408 I thought so and tried with different name too but didn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm var_dump the value of $post and see if it will ever have “U” as a value ?

Comment: @113408 its returning `false` for the second appraoch `bool(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first approach will not work as `$isType` will always be `false`. Because it’s not initialized and even when you initialize it with your function `isType($post)` you give it `true`as a value. However you check in your `headJS()` if `$this->isType ==‘U’` so always false.

For the second approach everything seems fine. My only guess is that you are calling `HeadJS()` before `isType($post)` or the value of `$post` is always different than ‘U’

Comment: This might be true. So is there anyway to overcome with the issue?

Comment: You said in another comment you’re using a CMS. Usually the CMS has a page lifecycle that you can use to call different function. Otherwise I would suggest you just call it inside ‘getItem()’ just after you call $this->isType($type)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to load the script in footer then it should work I believe.

Answer (score 0):

you have missed $ sign at `$this->isType(type);`.

You have to just call `$this->headJS();` after `$this->isType = true;`

```
class UserRatings extends User {

private $isType = false;


public function headJS(){

    // even this doesnt't work too
    if ($this->isType) {
        # code...
    }

}


public function getItem($post){

    $markup = 'html markup to render the output';

    $type = $post['data']['post_type'];

    $this->isType($type);

}

public function isType($post)
{
    if ($post == 'U') {
        $this->isType = true;
        $this->headJS();
    }

    return $this->isType;
}
}
```

Comment: This is CMS system made by someone and I cannot call this into `isType` method for some reason. My point is why the `$isType` doesn't hold the value? What I am doing wrong or who class member works?

Comment: @CodeLover you have missed `$` sign at $this->isType(type);

Comment: That is I forgot during the post but all is okay in my code file. Else it would give me error.. right?